# Android multipart upload + blueimp UploadHandler: filetype not allowed

Tags: java, php, android, upload, blueimp

I'm trying to get my Android multipart image upload to work with the default blueimp PHP UploadHandler, which I'm using for the web version of my app.
It didn't work out of the box, so I experimented with the header of the requests.
I played around with it for quite a while, but since nothing worked I ended up firing up Wireshark and comparing the packets of the blueimp demo and the ones that are sent by the Android app.
After some further tweaking, they look exactly the same (well the important parts):
Blueimp demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7o26.png
Android MultipartEntity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjxHp.png
This is what my customized `generate_response` function returns:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
      [name] => 1387215600-9207
      [size] => 97894
      [type] => multipart/form-data; boundary=-----Don'tmindmeI'mjustaboundary
      [error] => Filetype not allowed
    )
)
```

It seems to load the whole packet instead of just it's multipart part.
Is there any way to fix that?

Here's how I create the request (not quite but these are the relevant lines):

```
public static String BOUNDARY = "-----Don'tmindmeI'mjustaboundary";

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, BOUNDARY, null);
File file = new File(params[2]); //params[2] contains the absolute path + filename
String filename = file.getName();
entity.addPart(filename, new FileBody(file, getMimeType(params[2]))); //getMimeType returns the MIME Type of the image e.g. image/png

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(params[0]); //params[0] contains the URL
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
request.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, context);
```

I've been working on this for hours and it's really driving me nuts.
What am I doing wrong?
**Edit:**
Nevermind I got it to work
I forgot to set the name of the form to files[], which is what the UploadHandler is looking for ...
So now it looks like this:

```
...
public static String BOUNDARY = "-----Don'tmindmeI'mjustaboundary";
...

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, BOUNDARY, null);

File file = new File(params[2]);
String filename = file.getName();

FileBody body = new FileBody(file, getMimeType(params[2]));
FormBodyPart part = new FormBodyPart("files[]", body);

part.addField("Content-Type", getMimeType(params[2]));
part.addField("Content-Disposition", "form-data; filename=\""+filename+"\"");

entity.addPart(part);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(params[0]);

request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+BOUNDARY);
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,es;q=0.4");

request.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, context);
...
```